# Is there a way to get the keyboard layout (which letter is where)?

Tags: vi, xkb

I have a very rarely used keyboard layout and there are a lot of things that are quite obviously not optimized for my very specific layout.
I would like to change hotkeys for a program but I would also like for it to help other people. Is there a way to get the letter that is returned by pressing the j key on my keyboard ?
To be specific I want to remap which letters are making the cursor move in vi (neovim) (which is just jkgh, etc., without a modifier). I also don't want to ruin things for myself if I happen to need to switch to qwerty.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> both have the problem that they are highly dependent from the fact that their inventors used a specific keyboard layout.
No, you cannot fully ameliorate this.

You can of course read X and kernel VT keyboard maps out from the X server and the KVTs, or at least know which ones you put in in the first place by reading their various configuration files.
But that only gets you as far as knowing which *key codes* produce which characters.
What it does not tell you is where the keys physically are that produce those key codes over the wire.

So at best you can guess that when (say) a `fr.kbd` keyboard map (to use the FreeBSD name) is in use <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keycodes coming in over the wire become <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> as seen by applications.
But you have no way to know that those keys physically form the required shape on the actual keyboard.

### Because:

Keyboards simply don't make this information available over the wire.
There are internal maps inside the keyboard that its microprocessor uses to translate the physical matrix into the USB HID usages, or PS/2 scancodes, that get sent over the wire.
There's no standard form for them, and no way for a host machine to read them off the keyboard.

#### For examples:

- There's no way to tell that a keyboard manufacturer has decided to make the entire numeric keypad accessible with [a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key modifier](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/fn-key-is-local.html) applied to several columns within the main alphanumeric block, as some small form factor laptop keyboards do.
  What gets sent over the wire is the same USB HID usages and PS/2 scancodes as for a numeric keypad elsewhere.
- The key that is usually engraved <kbd>~#</kbd> is at ISO 9995-1 position D13 on 104-key Windows keyboards, but is at position C12 on 105-key, 106-key, 107-key, and 109-key Windows keyboards.
  This physical movement of the key is not signified anywhere over the wire to the host.
  The host receives the *same single* USB HID usage and PS/2 scancode.
- Most applicably to <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, keyboards that remap the matrix at the keyboard end, in response to a switch on the keyboard itself, blow up the idea of <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> becoming <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

  - Switch [a Maltron keyboard](http://www.maltron.com/store/p10/Maltron_L90_dual_hand_fully_ergonomic_%283D%29_keyboard_-_UK_English.html) from QWERTY mode into Maltron mode using the switch on the keyboard, and suddenly the <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys are sending the keycodes for <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> over the wire.  Apply the `fr.kbd` map to that and applications see <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> characters.
  - Switch [a Maltron keyboard](http://www.maltron.com/store/p10/Maltron_L90_dual_hand_fully_ergonomic_%283D%29_keyboard_-_UK_English.html) from QWERTY mode into Maltron mode using the switch on the keyboard, and suddenly the <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> keys are sending the keycodes for <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>H</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> over the wire.  Apply the `us.dvorak.kbd` map to that and applications see <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> characters.

### Some irony

Ironically, the cursor diamond layout has existed for longer than Unix has.
A GE Datapro-760 from 1966 had cursor keys, not quite in the modern diamond layout, but close.
For a physical shape to rely upon universally, that comes close; because very few keyboard manufacturers physically position the cursor keys in anything other than diamond, square, or single row.

The sad thing is that we are where we are in Unix because Bill Joy had an ADM 3A.
If xe had had a DEC VT52 or a Beehive B100, both of which also came out in 1976 but had cursor keys, we'd probably have a rather different vi tradition now, and you wouldn't be trying to find out how to know where <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> are physically laid out on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can start reading here: [https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_1)](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))

Also, you can issue command like:

```
cat /dev/tty
```

And pressing actual keys - you will see how keyboard driver recognize them.

Comment: This would still require me to map every single key individually and for every single keymap I use. I would love to automate at least one of those two.